# Configure Android to save pictures/video to SDCard

Tags: internal-storage, photos, external-sd

Just installed a 32gb SD card in my Samsung S2.  Is there a way to configure ICS to save all pictures/videos to the SD card instead of internal memory?

Comment: Have you looked in the settings for your Camera app?

Comment: that's it - I overlooked the obvious.  I can either delete this, or if you'll add this as the answer I'll select & give some karma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this from the settings of the Camera app, rather than the system settings.

Comment: At least in most cases. I was looking for that in many device's camera apps (stock and 3rd party) where it was missing, unfortunately...

Comment: @Izzy That's true.  In those cases you might be able to get away with a symlink or something.

Comment: Why didn't I get that idea myself? Thanks for the hint!